# Bash localizing

Tags: bash, localization

I am playing with localizing bash scripts:

I created the file /tmp/hello.sh with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash  
LANGUAGE=es_ES   
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/home/adrian/tmp/locale  
TEXTDOMAIN=hello  
echo $"Hello, world"
```

Generate hello.pot:

```
bash --dump-po-strings hello.sh
```

Now `hello.pot` contains:

```
:   hello:2  
msgid "Hello, world"  
msgstr "Hola ..."
```

If I run

```
sudo msgfmt -o /home/adrian/tmp/es/LC_MESSAGES/hello.mo hello.pot
LANGUAGE=es_ES ./hello
```

it does not work. If only works when I copy the mo file to /usr/local/share/locale/es/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command below needs to match the variable in your script (or vice versa):

```
sudo msgfmt -o /home/adrian/tmp/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/hello.mo hello.pot
```

Note the addition of `locale`.

See [How to add localization support to your bash scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/098) and [Internationalizing Those Bash Scripts](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/internationalizing-those-bash-scripts).